# Pyramid Pattern in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

It was so hard to ask such a newbie question on this advanced site. But after so much tries and even loosing my hope i was forced to bring my self here. I am not been able to print the following pattern:

```
                    1                                                                                                                              
                1   2   1   
            1   2   4   2   1   
        1   2   4   8   4   2   1   
    1   2   4   8   16  8   4   2   1
1   2   4   8   16  32  16  8   4   2   1
```

But with my tiresome efforts i reached the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 15 - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


           1 
          1 1 
         1 1 1 
        1 1 1 1 
       1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 1 
     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: You realize that you never change `num`, right?

Comment: you need to update num, and keep track of where you are in the line. if notyetinhalf, num+=1; else num -= 1;

Comment: you make `i++` although you need line lengths of 1,3,5,7...

Comment: all the numbers of your pyramid are powers of 2... think of how to get the exponent according to your position in the particular row! it's not that hard to achieve...

Comment: I understand now. I will give a try and will be back again.

Comment: For me you should remember last row (in array???), create current row (size +1) and repeat step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ya go

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max = 6;
    int padLength = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(Math.pow(2, max) + 1)) + 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < max - i; j++) {
            System.out.print(pad(" ", padLength));
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print(pad(Math.pow(2, k), padLength));
        }
        for (int k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            System.out.print(pad(Math.pow(2, k), padLength));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static String pad(double d, int l) {
    Integer i = (int) d;
    return pad(i.toString(), l);
}

public static String pad(String s, int l) {
    return String.format("%-" + l + "s", s);
}
```

## Explanation

#### `int padLength = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(Math.pow(2, max) + 1)) + 2;`

`Math.pow(2,max)` - Gives me maximal number I will have to display

`Math.ceil(Math.log10(number + 1))` - I use this to determine length of string representation of specific `number`. [Please refer to wikipedia to check what logarithm is.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) I add 1 to skip edge case when number is exact power of 10 e.g. `log10(10)->1` (this will never occur in task specified in question, it's just for purity of solution). Ceil just rounds number up.

`+2` - minimum gap between two numbers is specified example was 2 spaces long so I just add this

You could use here `Integer.toString(((int)Math.pow(2, max))).length()+2` but it's not as pretty :)

#### `return String.format("%-" + l + "s", s);`

First I build format string that looks like e.g. `%-3s`, which means print `String` with minimum length of 3, padding on the right. Second argument is the String I want to print. Refer to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

#### [Running example](https://ideone.com/7YKfrT)

Comment: This is the only answer which works 100% correctly for any input. There is no distortion in output. good one. My answer sucked, so i deleted it.

Comment: can you please tell me the logic for generating the padding ? thanks.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev hey I added explanation. I hope it helps.

Comment: @mleko THUMBS UP MAN. its awesome logic

Answer (score 1):

I find the other answer very overwhelming and dramatic. You don't need much maths and complexity to solve this problem. This might not be the best code but I think it is easy to understand. Not even an explanation is needed, it is a row by row approach, It's good to keep things simple.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Init
    int row = 0;
    int maxRows = 6;
    int num = 1;
    int indent = maxRows - 1;

    // Printing loop
    while (row < maxRows) {

        // Indent
        for (int i = 0; i < indent; ++i) 
            System.out.print("    ");

        // Print nums
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) 
            System.out.printf("%4d", (int) Math.pow(2.0, i));
        for (int i = num - 2; i >= 0; --i)
            System.out.printf("%4d", (int) Math.pow(2.0, i));

        // New line
        System.out.println(""); 

        // Adjustments
        ++row;
        --indent;
        ++num;
    }
```

Output:

```
                               1
                           1   2   1
                       1   2   4   2   1
                   1   2   4   8   4   2   1
               1   2   4   8  16   8   4   2   1
           1   2   4   8  16  32  16   8   4   2   1
```