# pyramid printing using Java

Tags: java

[Pyramid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcLnO.png)

Note:

1. System.our.printf(“%n.mf”, num) will print out a float number num with width n and m decimal places.
2. Calculation of a^b in Java:  Math.pow(a,b)
3. For the above pyramid printing, you may break the pattern into three parts: spaces on the left, numbers on the left and numbers on the right. For each line i, there are total 2*i-1 numbers.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 5, k = 0, count = 0, count1 = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
            for(int space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space) {
                System.out.print("  ");
                ++count;
            }

            while(k != 2 * i - 1) {
                if (count <= rows - 1) {
                    System.out.print((i + k) + " ");
                    ++count;
                }
                else {
                    ++count1;
                    System.out.print((i + k - 2 * count1) + " ");
                }

                ++k;
            }
            count1 = count = k = 0;

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You should start by [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I hope this is useful to you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030676/pyramid-pattern-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I decided to give this a try, mainly because I wanted to present some concepts having to do with problem-solving.

First, I made the height of the pyramid a variable.  This forced me to consider how different pyramid heights would affect the width of each segment of each line.

Next, I decided to pre-calculate the powers of two.  There's no point in recalculating the values for each line.  So, I wrote a method to return a precalculated array of integers.

Next, I calculated how much space the largest power of two would take up.  I formatted the number using the `NumberFormat` class.  The `NumberFormat` class will format the number according to the `Locale` in which you're running the code.  I used the `format` method of the `String` class to give each number enough space.

Next, I divided each line into a blank area, a number area, and a blank area.  That way, I could work on each part of a line separately.  The blank area on the left side of the pyramid line is the same length as the blank area on the right side of the line, so I only had to create it one time for each line.

I used a `StringBuilder` to create each line of the pyramid.  It's faster to use a `StringBuilder` than to concatenate `String` values.  I used `StringBuilder` segments to create the parts of a pyramid line.

I didn't use `static` methods because I wanted to show how you instantiate the class in the `main` method.  In general, I try to avoid the use of `static` methods.

Here's the result of one test run.  I assure you, I ran several dozen tests on this code.

```
                                             1                                             
                                        1    2    1                                        
                                   1    2    4    2    1                                   
                              1    2    4    8    4    2    1                              
                         1    2    4    8   16    8    4    2    1                         
                    1    2    4    8   16   32   16    8    4    2    1                    
               1    2    4    8   16   32   64   32   16    8    4    2    1               
          1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128   64   32   16    8    4    2    1          
     1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256  128   64   32   16    8    4    2    1     
1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256  512  256  128   64   32   16    8    4    2    1
```

Here's the code.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class NumberPyramid {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int power = 10;
        
        NumberPyramid np = new NumberPyramid();
        np.createPyramid(power);
    }
    
    private static final NumberFormat NF = 
            NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    
    public void createPyramid(int power) {
        int[] values = createPowersArray(power);
        String maximum = NF.format(values[power - 1]);
        int segmentSize = maximum.length() + 2;
        String format = "%" + segmentSize + "s";
        
        for (int index = 0; index < power; index++) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder blankArea = createBlankArea(
                    index, power, segmentSize);
            builder.append(blankArea);
            builder.append(createNumberArea(index, values, format));
            builder.append(blankArea);
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }
    }

    private int[] createPowersArray(int power) {
        int[] values = new int[power];
        values[0] = 1;
        
        for (int i =  1; i < power; i++) {
            values[i] = values[i - 1] * 2;
        }
        
        return values;
    }
    
    private StringBuilder createNumberArea(int index, 
            int[] values, String format) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int j = 0; j <= index; j++) {
            builder.append(String.format(format, 
                    NF.format(values[j])));
        }
        
        for (int j = index - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            builder.append(String.format(format, 
                    NF.format(values[j])));
        }
        
        return builder;
    }
    
    private StringBuilder createBlankArea(int index, 
            int power, int segmentSize) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < power - index - 1; i++) {
            builder.append(createBlankSegment(segmentSize));
        }
        
        return builder;
    }
    
    private StringBuilder createBlankSegment(int length) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            builder.append(" ");
        }
        
        return builder;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

find the answer below:

```
public class Main {

    static int rows = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= rows ; i++){
            if(i ==1 ) numbers.add(1);
            else {
                int totalNumber = i * 2 -1;
                    insertNumbers(totalNumber, numbers);
            }
            printNumbers(numbers, i);
            System.out.println();
            numbers.clear();
        }
    }

    private static void insertNumbers(int totalNumber, LinkedList<Integer> numbers) {
        int numbersOnEachSide = (totalNumber - 1) / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbersOnEachSide ; i++ ) numbers.add((int) Math.pow(2, i));
        numbers.add((int) Math.pow(2,numbersOnEachSide));
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numbersOnEachSide ; i++) numbers.add((int) Math.pow(2, numbersOnEachSide-1-i));
    }

    private static void printNumbers(LinkedList<Integer> numbers, int i) {
        int spaceNorows = rows - i;
        printSpaces(spaceNorows);
        for (Integer number : numbers) {
            System.out.print(number + "\t");
        }
        printSpaces(spaceNorows);
    }

    private static void printSpaces(int spaceNorows) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j< spaceNorows ; j++) System.out.print("\t");
    }

}
```

output:

```
                                    1                                       
                                1   2   1                                   
                            1   2   4   2   1                               
                        1   2   4   8   4   2   1                           
                    1   2   4   8   16  8   4   2   1                       
                1   2   4   8   16  32  16  8   4   2   1                   
            1   2   4   8   16  32  64  32  16  8   4   2   1               
        1   2   4   8   16  32  64  128 64  32  16  8   4   2   1           
    1   2   4   8   16  32  64  128 256 128 64  32  16  8   4   2   1       
1   2   4   8   16  32  64  128 256 512 256 128 64  32  16  8   4   2   1
```

p.s please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour to ask a proper question in later posts.

**EDIT : How to run the code in `CMD`**

To run the application above:

1- save all the code above in a file named - for example - Main.java

2- run `CMD` in windows or `terminal` in linux and compile the `Main.java` using `javac Main.java`.

3- The compiled file will be put in the same directory as the `java` file.

4- run the compiled class using `java Main`.

- change `Main` to whatever name you give to the file
- Since you are running the code in the cmd it might not display the 10 row pyramid properly(due to screen resolution, size, etc). So,
  change the row field in `static int rows = 10;` to `5` to see the
  pyramid properly.
- You can further changing the fixed row number to dynamically get it from user.

Comment: Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    private static void insertNumbers(int totalNumber, LinkedList<Integer> numbers) {
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class LinkedList
  location: class Main

Comment: I have provided all the methods.Did you copy the methods `insertNumbers` `printNumbers` `printSpaces` beside the main method?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, may i know how to run the code? type java Main in cmd?

Comment: may I know how can i fix the error mentioned above? please

Comment: may I know how can i fix the error mentioned above?Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol private static void insertNumbers(int totalNumber, LinkedList<Integer> numbers) { ^ symbol: class LinkedList location: class Main

Comment: @New are you using an IDE or you want to run it in cmd?

Comment: i want to run it in cmd. Thnaks!